# NetBeans created Jar file "cannot find main method"

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, program-entry-point, executable-jar

I realize there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of the answers are helping me.

I have a project that I made in netbeans and after setting as my main project I did a clean build.  I win.rar-ed the created .jar file and the library file in the dist folder.  The jar file runs fine on MY PC. However, when I copy the .rar file on to my flashdrive and try to run the .jar file on any other computer it gives me a missing main method error.

The manifest.mf file only contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

This is my first attempt at packing a program as a .jar file so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: have you set the main class in your application before making jar ?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents..

**First idea:** Fix configuration problem
Check Project configuration. Right click on your Project: Properties -> Run
Is `Main Class` attribute well defined?

**Second one:** Get a fresh and well defined build! (Ant XML file/targets and so on)

- Create New Project - Category [Java] Project [Java Application]
- Import existing sources to this new one
- Define the Main Class as above

Good luck!